# Solution to $\frac{d^2x(t)}{dt^2}+\omega(t)^2x(t)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

In physics, the simple harmonic oscillator with a time-dependent frequency $\omega(t)$ obeys the differential equation

\begin{align}
\frac{d^2x(t)}{dt^2}+\omega(t)^2x(t)=0\ .
\end{align}

If $\omega$ is a constant, then

\begin{align}
x(t)=C_1e^{i\omega t}+C_2e^{-i\omega t}\ .
\end{align}

How would I find a solution to the differential equation if $\omega(t)$ is an arbitrary time-dependent function? I tried looking in books on solutions to differential equations (such as [Handbook of exact solutions for ordinary differential equations](https://www.crcpress.com/Handbook-of-Exact-Solutions-for-Ordinary-Differential-Equations/Zaitsev-Polyanin/p/book/9781584882978)). All solutions I found are for a specific form of $\omega(t)$, rather than an arbitrary $\omega(t)$.

I also tried the substitution $x(t)=s(t)e^{i\gamma(t)}$. Assuming $s(t)$ and $\gamma(t)$ are both real functions, then subbing $x(t)$ into the above differential equation and splitting the result into its real and imaginary terms, I find the $s(t)$ and $\gamma(t)$ satisfy

\begin{align}
\frac{d^2s(t)}{dt^2}-s(t)\left(\frac{d\gamma(t)}{dt}\right)^2+\omega(t)^2s(t)=0\ ,\\
s(t)\frac{d^2\gamma(t)}{dt^2}+2\frac{ds(t)}{dt}\frac{d\gamma(t)}{dt}=0\ ,
\end{align}

but these equations are more complicated than my starting point.

Comment: Why do you assume that the coefficient function $s$ is real? Set $\frac{dγ(t)}{dt}=\pmω(t)$ to have the second and third term cancel. The remaining function should have a slower oscillation.

Comment: @LutzL The initial assumption is $s=\vert x \vert$ and $\omega = \arg(x)$, i.e. the polar form of the complex function $x$. But I like your substitution better

Comment: You get two basis solutions, the real solution is a linear combination of them. If you want to stay real use $x(t)=s_1(t)\cos(γ(t))+s_2(t)\sin(γ(t))$, but the equation you get does not look initially as nice as with the complex basis solutions.

Comment: @LutzL I assume that $s$ is real so, as Dylan wrote, I can decompose my solution into a polar form.

Why can I set $\frac{d\gamma(t)}{dt}=\pm\omega(t)$? Doesn't that constrain what the solution of $x(t)$ can be? Or are you saying to make $s$ complex with $\frac{d\gamma(t)}{dt}=\pm\omega(t)$, then solve the resultant differential equation for $s$? Though, based on Chappers answer, it doesn't look like the resultant differential equation may be a general closed-form solution either.

Comment: You are parametrizing the solution with two functions. Thus you have one functional relation free to simplify the resulting differential equation. What I gave is one useful variant. There is an infinity of other variants that may or might not prove useful in simplifying the equation or giving insights into the hull curve or asymptotic behavior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no general closed-form solution. For small $\omega(t)$, one can often obtain a power series approximation (or use the [Method of Frobenius](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusMethod.html) if a regular singular point occurs).

For large $\omega(t)$, an approximate solution can be generated using the [Liouville–Green formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKB_approximation): put $x(t) = e^{S(t)} $, and the equation becomes
$$ S'^2 + S'' = \omega^2. $$
If you now assume a solution of the form $S = S_0 + S_1 + S_2 + \dotsb$, where $S_k \gg S_{k+1}$ this equation is formally equivalent to the equations
$$ S'^2 = -\omega^2 \\
2S_0' S_1' + S_0'' = 0 \\
2S_{k}S_0 + S_{k-1}'' + \sum_{n=1}^{k-1} S_n' S_{n-k}' = 0, $$
which can be solved order-by-order. The first two terms are $S_0 = \pm i\int^t \omega(s) \,ds$ and $S_1 = -\frac{1}{2}\log{\omega}$.

There are conditions that are required for this to work, namely the above inequalities between the $S_k$, and $S_{N+1} \ll 1$ so that the error in the exponential is small ($e^{O(1)}$ is not $1+O(1)$ in general).

In particular, in many cases this gives $e^{S_0+S_1} = \omega^{-1/2}\exp{\left(\pm i\int^t \omega(s) \, ds \right)}$ as the leading-order behaviour in $\omega$, which does agree with the solution you have when $\omega$ is constant.